# Not able to change registry database wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Please Help!!!!!!!!Anyone please provide steps to change registry db from H2 to MySQL in WSO2[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Identity Server, 5.9.0 Registry data is stored in WSO2_SHARED_DB. by default this database is using embedded H2 database. You can change this by configuring deployment.toml file. Please follow the following documentation for instructions of changing it to a mysql database.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/setup/changing-to-mysql/

Comment: I have followed this documentation but it is not reflecting in the console and i am using the same version......